# NodeJS: Not able to find the npm package for strava_api_v3

Tags: node.js, google-fit, fitbit, garmin, strava

I'm working on the starva to get the athletes details. While referring their site they have mentioned to install the package "**strava_api_v3**"  but it was not available in the npm package.
Kindly share the link (or) npm installation process for the package strava_api_v3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Strava javascript API package is generated with `swagger-codegen` tool.

For MacOS install the tool and Maven with `brew install swagger-codegen@2 maven -g`.
Then generate the package and link it so that you can use it locally like this (make sure to replace PATH to wherever swagger-codegen binary is installed):

```
  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/swagger-codegen@2/2.4.26/bin
  swagger-codegen generate -i https://developers.strava.com/swagger/swagger.json -l javascript -o strava-api-v3
  cd strava-api-v3
  npm link
  cd ../{your-project-root}
  npm link strava_api_v3
```

After this you will be able to import is as `const StravaApiV3 = require('strava_api_v3')`

References: https://developers.strava.com/docs
The information on how to use the generated javascript module is in the generated README.md