# Where to find strava_api_v3 JS file?

Tags: javascript, strava

I want to implement the strava API into the Javascript application. I am totally new to this
I need to know from where to download this strava_api_v3.JS? Can someone guide me on this?

https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the file I am looking out for gets generated via swagger

[NodeJS: Not able to find the npm package for strava_api_v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68753534/nodejs-not-able-to-find-the-npm-package-for-strava-api-v3)